# How to remove the limit of how many desktop spaces can be opened in mission control?

Tags: macos, mac

The title says it. I'd like to remove the limitation of **15** additional desktop spaces from mission control. Is there a way how to do it (for ex. by tweaking some plists or from cocoa app in code)?

Comment: AFAIK one can only add spaces above 15 by going into full-screen mode with an app. An app that goes full screen creates its own desktop space.

Comment: you are right, this is maybe something I missed! I was able to create Desktop 1 to Desktop 16, and added to it at least 5 other apps were in fullscreen mode, so that's definitely a way of making that number larger! Thank you :)

Comment: Since you like it, I have added an answer with a reference.

Comment: I'd like to do the contrary.. i always find myself having 20+ unused desktops.. and i can't understand why. Maybe when using fullscreen apps OS X creates a desktop that's not being destroyed after closing the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short: No. You can't change the settings.**

The file `com.apple.spaces.plist` defines settings for each virtual desktop, but I couldn't find any signs of a numerical limit. Therefore I believe that the limit is somehow hardcoded in the script that creates new spaces.

I however found a (hackish) way to add more than 16 virtual spaces to one display:

1. Connect the secondary display to your Mac.
2. Create 16 virtual spaces on the secondary display.
3. Disconnect the display.

You should now have 31 virtual spaces on one display.

Proof:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is very cool! Is the hack stackable? As in, you disconnect the external display, you get the 31 virtual spaces, you add the display and you can add 15 more? Or the desktops get snapped back to the external display, limiting the maximum number of desktops?

You also mentioned script that creates new spaces. Any clues on where to find it or how to change it directly?

Comment: No. Once you connect your display back, your virtual spaces will be moved back the secondary display. You probably could increase the number of virtual spaces by increasing the number of physical displays (like connecting more throught USB). As i wrote before, I wasn't able to find any traces of limit in preferences files.

Comment: Okay, this is enough for me. Thanks for the effort! (also sending greetings from Vsetin)

Answer (score 1):

From [How to add more desktop spaces](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165649/how_to_add_additional_desktop_spaces.html) :

> You can create up to 15 additional desktop spaces in Mission Control
>   (16 total desktops, plus Dashboard). If you create the maximum number
>   of desktop spaces in Mission Control, you can still add new spaces by
>   going into full-screen mode with an app.
>
> Apps that support full-screen mode will have the full-screen icon in
>   the upper right corner. Click on it, and the app goes full screen and
>   creates its own desktop space.
>
> [image]
>
> When you launch an app and set it to full-screen mode, a space
>   dedicated to that app is created automatically. The catch is that you
>   must be using an app that supports full-screen mode for this to
>   happen. An app that supports full-screen mode will have a pair of
>   arrows in the upper right corner of its interface.
>
> When you have an app in full-screen mode, its thumbnail will appear in
>   Mission Control at the end of the thumbnail list with the name of the
>   app instead of Desktop 1, Desktop 2, etc.
>
> [image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now up to 59 desktops: [image: proof]

Just like Marakoss said, plug in an external monitor or projector and add an extra 16 spaces there. Though make sure you turn off mirroring if you have it on.

Though in my experience I plugged in the same external monitor weeks or months later, and it somehow had the option of adding more (go more than 16 extra spaces).

Now I'm up to 46 desktops, so just saying that more than 32 is possible.

[image: proof]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for chiming in. As it stands, though, your answer isn't very helpful to understand *how* to achieve what the original poster wanted. Care to investigate more and report back? Or, maybe, if you don't have the time or inclination to do that, add a comment where you think it could be useful?

Comment: Is that a bit clearer?

Comment: sure, thank you for taking the time to improve your answer!